# Center SVG, preserveAspectRatio not working

Tags: css, svg

I want my SVG to be centered but it looks like this:

[image: SVG not centered]

I'm trying to do `preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet"` to center it, but I'm obviously doing something wrong.

My tree and styling looks like this:

[image]

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I think the `viewBox` attribute is mandatory, when you try to use `preserveAspectRatio`.

Comment: Yes! It worked if I added a viewBox! Thanks a lot :D

Comment: Use a viewBox like `viewBox="0.19 0.25 6.92 3.75"` Remove the padding.

Answer (score 0):

An svg is inline by default, add these lines to the .triangle class to center it:

```
display: block;
margin: 0 auto;
```

This will center it horizontally, if you want vertical, follow these steps ->

Add these lines to the .triangle class:

```
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
```

Add this line to your .icon_icon_3iAWn class:

```
position: relative;
```